# Publications are not loading in WEB 8.1

Tags: web8

I am using WEB 8.1 and the issue which i am facing is publications are not loading and getting below error.

I have checked port 2660 is open and net.tcp is allowed in IIS  .
Any help would be highly appreciated

**Error:**

> Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://web8-cms.com:2660/ExternalContentLibrary/2012/netTcp. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0312515. TCP
>   error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it web8-cms.com:2660. No connection could be
>   made because the target machine actively refused it web8-cms.com:2660

Answer (score 1):

The net tcp endpoint is not provided by IIS. You need to check the TcmServiceHost service. First check that it is running.

If the service is running, then check that there is no firewall blocking the port.

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with the Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Web.config files configuration
We checked the following, they were mapped to the DNS Name of the SDL Web. These should always be localhost:. We did following changes and the error got resolved.

In appSettings Node:
key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="localhost:80"

In serviceHostingEnvironment\baseAddressPrefixFilters Node:
prefix="localhost:80"

In system.serviceModel\client\endpoint Node:
name="EclBinaryEndpoint" address="net.tcp://localhost:2660/ExternalContentLibrary/2012/netTcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EclNetTcpBinding" contract="Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

[image]

I was able to fix this by starting the services.

- Hit Windows Key+ R, type "services.msc".
- Search for "SDL Web Content Manager Service Host" services is running or not.
- If status is not "running",  right click on it and click on Start.

[image]